# How to open a set of tabs together quickly?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, tabbed-browsing

How to open a set of tabs together quickly?

I normally use "Pin Tab" in a session, and if Chrome is closed normally, the previous set of pinned tabs will be opened pinned automatically next time.  But sometimes:

- Chrome is closed in a crash, or
- I am just working on a different computer where I did not log in my Google profile

In those two cases, how do I open a predefined set of tabs quickly?  It is a bunch of webapps I frequent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to chrome://chrome/settings/ > Under "On startup" > Choose Open a specific page or set of pages. Here you can specify URLs of pages that you want to automatically launch every time on startup.

[image]

Another thing you could do is, bookmark all your frequently visited apps in a folder. You can launch all those bookmarks in a single-click when necessary. This gives better control in my opinion.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.  Just list the URLs as arguments to the Chrome program.  In Windows for example:

```
Path\To\Chrome\chrome.exe superuser.com stackoverflow.com google.com
```

Again in Windows, you could create a batch file with that and a shortcut to it, for any set(s) of tabs you frequent.

A similar approach should work on any OS Chrome supports, because the command line should function the same.

Comment: Good idea! But there's no need for a batch file. A simple shortcut to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe superuser.com stackoverflow.com google.com` will suffice.

Comment: True. But there is a character limit on shortcuts so you can't include too many long URLs.

Answer (score 2):

There is add-on for chrome called [tabcloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof) which is nice for that.