# How to open multiple URLs in Chrome/Firefox and then save them individually?

Tags: batch, url, browser-tabs

If I have a .txt file containing a list of URLs, how can I get Chrome or Firefox to open them, one URL per tab and then save the page in each tab separately?

Any platform will do: Windows, Mac, Linux.

Comment: One way would be to use a [multiple url opener tool](http://codegena.com/generator/multiple-url-opener) to automatically open all links within a text and then save them individually.

Comment: Found another multiple url opener site http://www.urlopener.com/homepage.html not sure what characters it recognizes as entry separators though.

Answer (score 18):

Opening the URLs in tabs can be done just pasting in a console prompt `cmd` your URLs like this.

```
start chrome http://yoururls/foo.html &
start chrome http://yoururls/bar.html &
.
.
.
```

or

```
start firefox http://yoururls/foo.html &
start firefox http://yoururls/bar.html &
.
.
.
```

Comment: On my computer with chrome, I can simply use the chrome command with the URL separated by space : chrome http://yoururls/foo.html http://yoururls/bar.html

Comment: This works but suffers of a race condition problem: some of the URLs are skipped randomly. In order to fix that I interleaved a `timeout 1 &` between each line. Not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Answering my own question, I was unsure of some plug-ins I had already seen but a closer look confirmed that they should do the job.

Two stages:

1. Run Firefox or Chrome from the command line, passing in the list of sites as parameter or a file containing a list, using one of the following methods:

   - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/opening-multiple-urls-from-a-text-file-as-different-tabs-in-firefox-chrome
   - [How to open a list of URLs in Firefox or SeaMonkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/385207/how-to-open-a-list-of-urls-in-firefox-or-seamonkey)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752133/script-to-automate-url-opening-in-multiple-tabs-in-firefox-or-opera-from-a-text
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045522/open-urls-from-a-file-in-newtabs-in-firefox
   - [How to open a set of tabs together quickly?](https://superuser.com/questions/417205/how-to-open-a-set-of-tabs-together-quickly)
   - [How can I open Google Chrome via command-line with a URL, in incognito mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/153245/chrome-command-line-arguments-w-url)
2. Then use one of the following plug-in as appropriate to save all the contents of each tab

   **Firefox:**

   - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/

   Quoted from the plug-in page (particular features of interest for this question):

   > About this Add-on: UnMHT provides following features:
   >
   > - Save webpage as MHT file.
   > - Insert URL of the webpage and date you saved into saved MHT file.
   > - Save multiple tabs as MHT files at once.
   > - Save multiple tabs into a single MHT file.
   > - Save webpage by single click into prespecified directory with Quick Save feature.
   > - Convert HTML files and directory which contains files used by the HTML into MHT file.
   > - View the MHT file saved by UnMHT, IE, PowerPoint, etc.

   **Chrome:**

   - Extension: [ZipTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ziptabs/ccnanbffbfbcgfmmkgejodommhidpjba)

   From the extension page:

   > - save multiple opened pages into a zip file containing single HTML files with all resources included (images, stylesheets, frames...)
   > - open a zip file containing archives into tabs Notes:
   > - this extension needs "SingleFile Core" to be already installed (follow install instructions)

Answer (score 9):

Although the question specifically mentions Chrome and Firefox, if what you are trying to do is to save the content of each page, [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/) is made for this task. E.g.:

```
wget --input-file=list_of_urls.txt
```

You can even specify a specific user-agent in case you want the server to see the request as a certain browser:

```
wget --user-agent=some_specific_user_agent_string --input-file=list_of_urls.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

For macOS you can just open terminal and use `open <URL>` to open all URLs separated by `&` like:

```
open https://www.google.com &
open https://www.youtube.com &
open https://www.facebook.com &
open https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

But keep in mind that tabs order won't be according to the command flow (i.e it won't open google first and StackOverflow last it will open in different orders).

If you have a .txt file you can use this command to open all URLs using terminal

```
cd <filePath> && while read -r url; do open "$url"; done < <filename>.txt
```

Note: This command will use your default browser.

Answer (score 3):

**Open all at once one on each tab from the command line (CLI)**

Chromium:

```
xargs chromium-browser --new-tab < urls.txt
```

Firefox:

```
xargs -L1 firefox -new-tab < urls.txt
```

or slightly more efficiently as per: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365399/xargs-append-each-argument-with-a-parameter

```
xargs printf -- '-new-tab %s\n' < urls.txt | xargs firefox
```

Test file:

urls.txt

```
https://example.com/1
https://example.com/2
https://example.com/3
```

Firefox needs a bit more work because it requires one `-new-tab` for every URL:

```
firefox -new-tab https://example.com/1 \
        -new-tab https://example.com/2 \
        -new-tab https://example.com/3
```

For the saving, you should just use `wget` instead of a browser as mentioned at: https://superuser.com/a/965286/128124

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10, Firefox 84, Chromium 85.

**Web-based URL openers**

There are several JavaScript based services out there, e.g. https://url-opener.com/ which are a good newb-proof solution that don't require installing anything.

You just paste the list of URLs into them, click "Open All", and they open one URL per tab.

You have to enable popups/multi-tab opening for the domain however, as those are blocked by default on most browsers to prevent ad spam. Browsers usually show a "Popup blocked" warning, which you can then click to disable.

TODO can't find an open source one on GitHub pages after searching for five minutes...

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/opening-multiple-urls-from-a-text-file-as-different-tabs-in-firefox-chrome

Comment: Please split one of these two solutions into a separate answer-post. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: I ask one of my friend to make tool for me, i use it for my office works now. try out https://pxl2rem.com/url-opener

Answer (score 1):

Getting all of the tabs to open separate through batch isn't too hard.

Code:

```
@echo off
open chrome [enter URL 1]
open chrome [enter URL 2]
...
exit
```

As for the saving, not sure if it's possible through batch.  I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I found in Firefox, is to install and use the SingleFile Extension, which has the "Batch save URLS" option ( and even the "Save selected links", "Save all tabs" etc. options, if you need it )

Here is a screenshot of its "Batch save URLS" option :

[image: "SingleFile's Batch save URLS" option]